# How to fix OSError: >;CG5= in python pybluez socket?

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, pybluez

I have the code:

```
import bluetooth, socket
addr = '70:4E:ED:20:E0:9C'
port = 1
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
s.connect( (addr, port) )
```

and I get OSError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 5, in <module>
  s.connect( (addr, port) )
File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", 
  line 96, in connect
bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
OSError: >;CG5=
```

how to fix it?